# Zappa set `app_function` correctly

Tags: python, flask, zappa

I have the following setup of my Flask application:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes.py
├── application.py
└── zappa_settings.json
```

`application.py`:

```
import os
from app import config_app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = config_app(os.environ, __name__)
    application.run(threaded=True)
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

def config_app(config, name=__name__):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(config)
    ...
    return app
```

Now I'm trying to deploy the application with `zappa` to AWS. When running `zappa init` it prompts for an `app_function`, however I'm not entirely sure what to set it to. So far I've tried

```
"app_function": "application.application"
```

Which returns a `502` error at the end.

Running `zappa tail`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 567, in lambda_handler
  return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 237, in lambda_handler
  handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 132, in __init__
  wsgi_app_function = getattr(self.app_module, self.settings.APP_FUNCTION)
AttributeError: module 'application' has no attribute 'application'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is the right format of the `application.py`:

```
application = config_app(os.environ, __name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     application.run(threaded=True)
```